# Draw text onto azimuthal projection map d3js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, azimuth

I've been working with this example: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/azimuthal.html and I have it displaying and working nicely with my own data. I see that in the example he gives a title to each country

```
feature.append("svg:title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });
```

Which works nicely. I would like to actually put text instead of a title though. So I want it to show up on top of the country as a label.

I tried this

```
feature.append("svg:text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.p.n; })
    .style("color", "#00FF33");
```

And many other combinations but nothing seems to be showing up. Interestingly I can use the Chrome inspector and I will correctly see `<text style="color: rgb(0, 255, 51);">Dominica</text>` inside of the path element, but I don't see it showing up on the map. Therefore clearly it's technically working in that it draws it with the correct text but I don't see anything showing up.

I can also for example render the text easily if I just do

```
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(collection.features)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:text")
    .text(function(d){
        return d.p.n;
    })
    .attr("x", function(d){
        return path.centroid(d)[0];
    })
    .attr("y", function(d){
        return  path.centroid(d)[1];
    })
    .attr("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr('font-size','6pt');
```

But this just draws them onto the map without regard to the existing countries and therefore they don't move along.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You are asking to nest a svg element `<text>` inside another svg element `<path>`. That's not actually possible — only `<g>` tags support that. `<title>` is a special case, which enables the tool tip, but nothing actually gets rendered in the SVG. Your other approach is the way to do it. So yes, you'll need to move the labels to where you want them to be. [Here's an example](http://bl.ocks.org/dwtkns/raw/4686432/).

Comment: Hmm that sucks but sounds reasonable. I'll try out the example you gave. Thanks! :)